# Book about a younger girl who lost her mother/child and was sad so she sat at a tree and became became it

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Okay, so there's a movie I remember I watched when I was younger, maybe like 8-10 years ago. So, I don't remember much, but I think it was a kind of horror movie. It was animated and more for kids, so you can imagine it's not that scary. So, a youngee girl either loses her mother or baby and there was a tree she was at all the time with them and eventually the tree grows over her and she basically becomes the tree. There's a boy, many many years later, that ends up finding this tree and a bunch happens and he frees the girl because all she needed was love, but she was hanging and kind of messing up his entire town. If you want to know the time frame in the movie in which this happens, you find out about the girls backstory and how everything happened at the end when she gets freed. The beginning is all about the boy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your title says she turned into a tree, but the body says she was trapped by it.  Which is correct?  Also, when and where did you see this?

Comment: Is it a book or movie? The title says one and the question says the other.